# How do I fetch and render 3 items from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, fetch

I'm trying to retrieve the top movies from themoviedb API (https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-popular-movies) and I can't seem to render them. I've successfully been able to console.log the data but I can't seem to render them.

I've tried a second useEffect with topThree as the dependency - no luck

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Carousel() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState<any[] | null>(null);
  const [topThree, setTopThree] = useState<any[] | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${process.env.MOVIE_API}`;
    axios(url).then(({data}) => {
      setTopThree(Object.entries(data.results).slice(0,3).map(entry => entry[1]));
    }).catch(err => {console.log(err.message);});
  }
  ,[]); 
  
  return topThree && (
    <>
      {topThree.map((movie) => {
        <>
          <h1>{movie.id}</h1>
          <p>{movie.title}</p>
        </>;
      })
      }
      <div className="absolute top-[15%] left-[10%]">
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Carousel;
```

I'm also trying to figure out how to type check the data with TS

```
interface IData {
  id: number,
  original_title?: string,
  title?: string,
  poster_path?: string | null,
  backdrop_path?: string | null,
  genre_ids?: number[]
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this. :)

Comment: when you log `topThree`, what do you have ?

Comment: what exactly are you successfully console.log-ing? The error? Where did you console.log the data? Also what is the div doing there? it looks a bit weird the syntax `<div className="absolute top-[15%] left-[10%]">`

Comment: can you show the consoled Img for more clarity and is there showing any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your data, the problem comes from here :

```
{topThree.map((movie) => {
        <>
          <h1>{movie.id}</h1>
          <p>{movie.title}</p>
        </>;
      })
      }
```

You should replace by :

```
{topThree.map((movie) => (
        <React.Fragment key={movie.id}>
          <h1>{movie.id}</h1>
          <p>{movie.title}</p>
        </React.Fragment>
 ))}
```

In your code you don't return your html in your map. That's why nothing is appearing.

And when you map through data and want to show it, it is better to add the `key` to the first element.

Second thing, with the line :

```
Object.entries(data.results).slice(0, 3).map((entry) => entry[1])
```

You can easily replace it by :

```
data.results.slice(0, 3)
```

as `data.results` is already an array.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that environment variable name always starts with REACT_APP_* e.g. process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIE_API

Now you don't have'nt described how does api response looks like, cause if you are able to fetch data from an api then there is problem with setting data to your topThree state.

Maybe you want to achieve something with this line but it does not seem to be working.

```js
setTopThree(Object.entries(data.results).slice(0,3).map(entry => entry[1]));
```

Please show me how your response looks like and i can help you out.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using nextjs, I've seen no issues without the "REACT_APP_" part, not sure if this does something else I'm unaware of though. Seems the issue was not returning anything via my map in the JSX.

Comment: in future if you ever encounter any problem with .env in nextjs, prefix your .env variables with NEXT_PUBLIC_